# How can I put and get a set of multiple items in a queue?

Tags: python, variables, task-queue

Worker:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        fruit, colour = q.get()
        print 'A ' + fruit + ' is ' + colour
        q.task_done()
```

Putting items into queue:

```
fruit = 'banana'
colour = 'yellow'
q.put(fruit, colour)
```

Output:

```
>>> A banana is yellow
```

How would I be able to achieve this? I tried it and got `ValueError: too many values to unpack`, only then I realized that my `q.put()` put both of the variables into the queue.

Is there any way to put a "set" of variables/objects into one single queue item, like I tried to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use a tuple:

```
fruit = 'banana'
colour = 'yellow'
q.put((fruit, colour))
```

It will be automatically unpacked.

Answer (score 1):

I just would make a list:

```
fruit = 'banana'
colour = 'yellow'
q.put([fruit, colour])
```

and then get it like that:

```
result = q.get()
fruit = result[0]
colour = result[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the best way to go about this is to refactor your data a bit.  Make some sort of object to hold a pair of values (in this case fruit and colour), and then put that object into the queue, then pull out the variables when needed.

I can post some sample code later if you would like.

Comment: yes, this is essentially what @dav1d 's answer does above, using a tuple as the value-holding object

Answer (score 0):

Python also provides data abstraction with the help of classes.

So, another approach can be to put an object (abstracting the related info together) with the help of a class as shown below.

```
class Fruit(object):
   def __init__(self, name, color):
       self.name = name
       self.color = color

q.put(Fruit('banana', 'yellow'))

def worker():
    while True:
        fruit  = q.get()
        print 'A ' + fruit.name + ' is ' + fruit.color
        q.task_done()
```

Comment: you can use `dataclasses.dataclass` decorator (since Py 3.7) to create a lighter attribute-only class using less memory and not need init, or  `collections.namedtuple` (since Py 2.6) for much better performance. `@dataclass` is easier to work with and can be mutable, but namedtuple is higher performance and treated as a tuple by other modules (such as numpy) with similar limitations, as such is usually a better choice if mutability is not needed.